# Apache Solr 4.10 didn't display some attributes which i listed in schema

Tags: solr, solr4

- I'm finding about Apache Solr. After i setup and index my data into Apache Solr. But when i tried to query data from Solr.
- I found that some attributes which i listed in `schema.xml` didn't display in result search. And i didn't understand why it didn't display.

This is my `schema.xml`

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />

<field name="title" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="type_music" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="format" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="album" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="singer" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="artist" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="lyrics" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="updated_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="site_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="rank" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="country" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="url_original" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="birthday_singer" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="information" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="category_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="image" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="quantity" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="lsxanh" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="nhachot" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="music_top" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<field name="default_field" type="text_vi" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

And this is file `data-config.xml`

```
<entity name="musics" pk="id"
query="select p.id, LCASE(p.title) as title, birthday_singer, p.type_music, LCASE(p.format) as format, p.album, LCASE(p.lyrics) as lyrics, LCASE(p.information) as information, LCASE(p.singer) as singer, p.artist, url, url_original, p.updated_at as updated_at, site_id, category_id, quantity, rank, country, image, lsxanh, nhachot, music_top from musics p order by updated_at desc;">
<field column="id" name="id" template="id"/>
<field column="title" name="title"/>
<field name="type_music" column="type_music" />
<field name="format" column="format" />
<field name="album" column="album" />
<field name="singer" column="singer" />
<field name="birthday_singer" column="birthday_singer" />
<field name="artist" column="artist" />
<field name="lyrics" column="lyrics" />
<field name="url" column="url" />
<field name="rank" column="rank" />
<field name="url_original" column="url_original" />
<field name="information" column="information" />
<field name="updated_at" column="updated_at" />
<field name="site_id" column="site_id" />
<field name="country" column="country" />
<field name="image" column="image" />
<field name="category_id" column="category_id" />
<field name="quantity" column="quantity" />
<field name="lsxanh" column="lsxanh" />
<field name="nhachot" column="nhachot" />
<field name="music_top" column="music_top" />
```

And this is result which i tried to query to database:

```
"response": {
"numFound": 3193,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "singer": "đông nhi",
    "default_field": [
      "đông nhi",
      "vì ai vì anh-"
    ],
    "format": "mp3",
    "title": "vì ai vì anh-",
    "type_music": "music hot",
    "url": "http://www.mysite.vn/Data_LSX/SONGS/5778/5794/Dong.mp3",
    "updated_at": "2015-08-09T01:59:18Z",
    "category_id": 0,
    "site_id": 2,
    "url_original": "http://www.mysite.vn/AlbumSongMovie.aspx?songid= 5794",
    "id": "3193",
    "nhachot": false,
    "lsxanh": true,
    "music_top": false,
    "_version_": 1508992864222183400
  }
```

And you can see, there are some fields didn't display in resuts such as:

- `image`
- `album`
- ...

I didn't understand why, hope everybody can explain for me. Why these fields didn't display in results. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please cross check with your DB and make sure image/album columns are not null for id 3193.

SOLR is not record based like our standard DB, it will just list a field if you have indexed a doc (here id 3193) with that field value.

For testing purpose, add this doc manually and confirm it lists for you or not?

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">1234</field>       
        <field name="image">image value 1</field>              
    </doc>
</add>
```